# Swift Subscript Error

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, option-type, subscript

I believe it has something to do with optionals, but I'm safely unwrapping sourceURL so I'm still not sure where the error is! I'm trying to access a JSON object's array's dictionary value.

However, I'm still getting the "could not find overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments.

It seems simple, but I just can't seem to figure it out!

```
        var dictTemp: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &localError) as? NSDictionary
        var finalURL: String
        // error line below
        if let sourceURL = dictTemp[0]["source"]["sourceUrl"] as? NSString {
            finalURL = sourceURL as String

        }
```

Comment: What type is `dictTemp`?

Comment: And by the way, `as? NSString ... as String` isn't necessary. You can just use `as? String`.

Comment: @jtbandes added to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Did it really? I'm still seeing the error. However, I believe you can use `dictTemp[0]?["source"]??["sourceURL"]`. Kind of a mouthful.

Comment: @jtbandes no you're right. sorry I got excited for a second I think xcode was just slow in giving me a new error message. will try that thanks

Comment: that works. could you post an answer as to why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSDictionary accessed from Swift is an interesting beast.

As long as Swift only knows something is an NSDictionary (not a more specific `[Key: Value]` Swift-style dictionary), you can only retrieve `AnyObject?`s out of it.

```
let dictTemp: NSDictionary = // from somewhere...

let step1 = dictTemp[0]  // step1 is an AnyObject?
```

But then, since you've imported Foundation, you can keep going with a magical subscript operator that works on `AnyObject`, and checks whether the thing is a dictionary:

```
let step2 = step1?["source"] // step2 is any AnyObject??
```

Here's where it gets interesting, because

- if `step1` was a dictionary with a "source" key inside it, `step2` will be the corresponding value.
- if `step1` was a dictionary ***without*** a "source" key, `step2` will be `nil` — in particular, it's `AnyObject??.Some(AnyObject?.None)`.
- if `step1` was nil (the original dictionary didn't have 0 as a key), or not a dictionary (it had a 0 key with some other kind of value), then `step2` will be `nil` — in particular, `AnyObject??.None`.

(The distinction between the last 2 cases is mostly unimportant and you shouldn't worry about it, but if you're interested you can see it by using `dump`).

And of course, we can apply the same principle again:

```
let step3 = step2??["sourceUrl"] // step3 is AnyObject?? again
```

Now, binding them all in one `if`:

```
if let url = dictTemp[0]?["source"]??["sourceUrl"] as? String {
    // do something with url...
}
```

#### Caveat

This type of syntax can be dangerous, since it works with arrays and dictionaries at the same time. What would you expect in these situations?

```
let dict: NSDictionary = [0: ["source": [3: "result"]]]

dict[0]?["source"]??[3] // returns nil (surprise!)
dict[0]?["source"]??[3 as NSNumber] // returns "result"

let dict2: NSDictionary = [0: ["source": [8, 7, 6, 5, 4]]]

dict2[0]?["source"]??[3] // returns 5
dict2[0]?["source"]??[3 as NSNumber] // returns nil (surprise!)
```

Comment: Still, why does AnyObject? return a double optional from a subscript while Dictionary? returns a single optional from a subscript? I guess it's just hard to get through my head why it would be that way, besides an oversight by the language designers.

Comment: Probably because `Dictionary` can always be queried for keys, whereas `AnyObject` may not even be a NSDictionary or NSArray at all. I agree though, it seems weird.