# swift2 possible unwrapping issue?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Here is a screenshot of my code, I hope that's better than pasting it so you can see exactly what xcode is telling me and on which line. I tried unwrapping (!) in different places on the line above it but I couldn't seem to figure out what I'm not unwrapping properly. I'm still learning swift2 so I'm sorry ahead of time if I'm missing something simple here...

EDIT: "if let" doesn't change the error produced for me. Also, I'm attaching my code in pasted form.

[image: screenshot of my code]

```
        let apiCode = "10861780"
    let myKey = "AIzaSyDkUBkhc-oSlhnW-4q3BTJ2neEpqPUsOZ8"

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/\(apiCode)/posts?key=\(myKey)")!

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let urlContent = data {

            do {

                let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlContent, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

                if let item = jsonResult["items"][0] as? NSDictionary {
                    print(item)
                }


            } catch {

                print("JSON ERROR")
            }
        }
    }


    task.resume()
```

Comment: instead of posting a picture you should post some code and the error... and picture of how your JSON looks like

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift Subscript Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623244/swift-subscript-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jsonResults["items"]` may or may not exist, so its type is the **optional** `AnyObject?`.

To index further you can use optional chaining, like

```
if let item = jsonResults["items"]?[0] as? NSDictionary ...
```

For more details, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623244/swift-subscript-error/31623329#31623329).

Comment: I changed it to [code]if let item = jsonResult["items"][0] as? NSDictionary {
                        print(item)
                    }[/code] but its still the same error

Comment: you missed a `?` from my suggestion.

Comment: Actually, I'm sorry...I missed that "?" you had after ["items"] and that was what I was missing.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you using Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7, we can use *guard*
check this below code:

```
 guard let item = jsonResults["items"]?[0] as? NSDictionary ... 
 else {   return    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to subscript **jsonResult["items"]**, but it is **AnyObject?**. You can not subscript because it is not a collection, list, or sequence.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html

You can subscript an array though...

If you expect **jsonResult["items"]** to be an array of dictionary's...

```
jsonResult["items"] as? [NSDictionary]
```

or

```
jsonResult["items"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]
```

Examples

```
if let items = jsonResult["items"] as? [NSDictionary?], item = items[0] {
    print(item)
}

if let items = jsonResult["items"] as? [[String: AnyObject]?], item = items[0] {
    print(item)
}

guard let item = jsonResult["items"] as? [[String: AnyObject]?], item = items[0] {
    return
}
print(item)
```